# Why does increasing the delay of setInterval cause it to decrease the delay?

Tags: javascript

I have a `setInterval(functionName, 1000)` in JavaScript. 
 It spawns images of mobs. I thought they were spawning too fast, so I switched the delay to 2000. It spawned even faster (I estimate the delay to be 100). Why does this happen? 
For those who wish to know my code:

```js
var spawner = setInterval(spawnZombie, 20000);
setInterval(moveZombie, 100);
function spawnZombie() {
  let zombProp = `_${zombNum}`;
  let zombID = `zomb${zombNum}`;
  let randomX = getRandom(500);
  let randomY = getRandom(1300);
  zombies[zombProp] = {};
  zombies[zombProp].hp = 3;
  zombies[zombProp].alive = true;
  zombies[zombProp].x = randomX;
  zombies[zombProp].y = randomY;
  zombies[zombProp].id = zombID;
  createElement("img", null, "map", "src", "sprites/zombie_right.png", "id", zombID);
  get(zombID).style.position = "absolute";
  get(zombID).style.top = `${randomX}px`;
  get(zombID).style.right = `${randomY}px`;
  zombNum++;
}
```

All variables are defined. The setInterval is attached to a variable so it can be cleared after 5 zombies are spawned and vice versa.

Comment: you'll have to share your actual code for anyone to know why

Comment: What's the code for `moveZombie`? The interval for this is very short.

Comment: moveZombie moves the zombies towards the player. It doesn't spawn any zombies and is not the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have a functionality that create a new function, "overlapping" over the existing cycle and, thus, it looks like the slider speeds up, but its just one cycle starting over another.

Comment: This happens every time and I forget that it can happen. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The number you provide to `setInterval` is the **period** of the interval. If you increase the period, you'll make it slower. If you want to make it faster, decrease the interval.

documentation for [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

```js
const log1sec = () => console.log('1 sec', new Date().getSeconds())

const log2sec = () => console.log('2 sec', new Date().getSeconds())

setInterval(log1sec, 1000)

setInterval(log2sec, 2000)
```

This seems to work

Comment: I asked why increasing the interval does not make it slower. Both increasing and decreasing the interval actually decreased the time between function calls.

Comment: edited the post to include an example, could you give it a try? @DaveRainbowin

Comment: I see, that's how the setInterval is supposed to behave. In my case, like I said, if the interval goes higher or lower the period becomes lower and the function is called faster. A note: turning the interval down speeds it up more than going up

Comment: Is your function asynchronous? Perhaps it has to do with what your functions does

Comment: Hold on, let me find out what asynchronous functions are